# Reading .ini file in QT with multiple tags

Tags: c++, qt, ini

1.For example

```
[Tag1]
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
 .
 .
[Tag2]
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
 .
 .
```

2. This is the format of my abc.ini file. I can read the values of tag1 but I am unable to read for tag2
3. This is my code for Tag1

   ```
   QSettings settings("abc.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
   settings.beginGroup("Tag1");
   const QStringList childKeys = settings.childKeys();
   QHash<QString,QString>values;
   foreach (const QString &childKey,childKeys)
   values.insert(childKey, settings.value(childKey).toString());
   settings.endGroup();
   qDebug()<<values;
   ```
4. Can anyone help me to read tag2 values and store them in the same QHash(values) which I defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
QSettings settings("file.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
QHash<QString,QString>values;

settings.beginGroup("Tag1");
QStringList childKeys = settings.childKeys();
foreach (const QString &childKey,childKeys)
values.insert(childKey, settings.value(childKey).toString());
settings.endGroup();

settings.beginGroup("Tag2");
childKeys = settings.childKeys();
foreach (const QString &childKey,childKeys)
values.insert(childKey, settings.value(childKey).toString());
settings.endGroup();

qDebug()<<values;
```

In your example, you have the same key in different groups, so it will erase the older value with **QHash**

But if you want to have multiple values in the same key, just replace **QHash** by **QMultiHash**

Answer (score 0):

you can begin/end as many groups as your app needs, so do that for the `tag2`, read the children and insert them in the map

```
foreach (const QString &childKey,childKeys)
values.insert(childKey, settings.value(childKey).toString());
settings.endGroup();
qDebug()<<values;
 
//BEGIN TAG2
settings.beginGroup("Tag2");
childKeys = settings.childKeys(); //or create a new list 
foreach (const QString& childKey,childKeys)
values.insert(childKey, settings.value(childKey).toString());
settings.endGroup();
qDebug() << values;
```

Comment: I tried this but I am not getting the output
childKeys = settings.childKeys(); //or create a new list at this line I am getting an error as 
 no viable overloaded '=' can you please see this

Comment: Solved sir, Thank you